# R - Calculate Most common path or route indoor place

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to calculate most common routes or paths in a indoor place done by different devices to get different clusters and draw it on a chart (simple plot).

I have a dataframe with coordinates (x / y) with detection datetime for every device:

```
>dataframe
        deviceID  x  y    detectionTime
    1     user05  8 10 2016-06-03 18:59:06
    2     user05 10 10 2016-06-03 18:59:07
    3     user05 12 10 2016-06-03 18:59:08
    4     user05 14 10 2016-06-03 18:59:09
```

I've tried to accomplish with different libraries in R but they are focused to draw paths with OpenMaps and long / lat parameters. I tried to make x and y columns as coordinates but I can't get the desired result.

I can plot all devices coordinates but it's not the result I need:

**With simple plot**

```
plot(rev(dataframe$x), rev(dataframe$y), type = "l", col = "red", 
        lwd = 3, bty = "n", ylab = "Y", xlab = "X")
```

**With ggplot**

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(dataframe$x, dataframe$y, color=dataframe$deviceID))+geom_point()
```

Comment: Why don't your attempts result in your desired result? What is your desired result? (Also in ggplot, once you specify `data = dataframe`, you do not need `dataframe$column` in the `aes()`).

Comment: The desired result is to have different clusters taking into account each device route. Maybe I have to do some preprocessing before making the plot.

Comment: Can you add a mocked-up image of your desired output? It is hard to understand what you mean by "different clusters taking into account each device route."